# How do I reduce edge loops without weird geometry?

Tags: modeling, vertices, edges, topology, faces

I'm trying to understand/learn modeling and I'm having problems reducing the number of edge loops I have without super weird geometry or awful triangles.

Here's a picture of what I'm trying to achieve (but without the weird geometry).

[image: example topology problem]

What's the best way to approach this problem?

Comment: Yeah but I want to keep the 3 edgeloops on the left and also keep the 1 edgeloop on the right, not delete them. Some areas of a model require more geometry, which then proceeds into an area that doesn't need as much.

Comment: Then you won't be able to go without some ngons. And I think these may be 5-vertices polys

Comment: Well if that's the only option, then what's the "cleanest" way to go about it? is really what I'm asking.

Comment: Do you mean you want to keep the vertical edgeloops at the left or the horizontal edgeloops?

Comment: @FacebFaceb Sorry if there was any confusion, I'm only referring to the horizontal edge loops. I want 3 horizontal edge loops on the left and one horizontal edge loop on the right, but without the weird transition geometry.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First off there is no way to reduce 3 inner edges to 0 without adding a loop cut somewhere, or using triangles or Ngons.

You can reduce three inner edges down to one inner edge using only quads.
[image: 3 to 1 reduction]

However you can reduce four inner edges down to zero. 
[image: 4 to 0 reduction]

Comment: I didn't specifically want to go from 3 to 0, I just wanted to go from X to X-1

Comment: Can you generalize your technique? How do you approach reducing detail...this is a really great post, I wish it had more though...