# How to avoid n-gons while using the knife tool?

Tags: modeling, topology

I keep encountering a problem, I started modeling 3 months ago and I keep reachign dead-ends because of n-gons.
Currently I am working on something that should become a claw, but I am stuck:

[image: Problem]

I want to give it another split so I can extrude 3 claws without having to add a whole new loopcut, but when I cut it with the knife tool..

[image: wrong]

I end up with two ngons, one at the bottom and one up where the cut ends, is there any other way than to make a loopcut for everything?

Comment: See: http://topologyguides.com/post/163679954765/loop-reduction

Comment: I.. have no idea what I am looking  at...

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/35895/how-do-i-reduce-edge-loops-without-weird-geometry/35903#35903

Answer (score 1):

Tap <kbd>K</kbd> to use the knife tool.
Click 2 or more lines, then <kbd>Enter</kbd> to complete your cut.

If you end up w/ unwanted n-gons, do the same operation, but cut across diagonal corners.

Another method is tap <kbd>Alt-P</kbd> to poke faces.

Alternatively, use the **triangulate** modifier.